# Is it possible to access a Windows PC with possibly dead video card w/out replacing the card?

Tags: windows, graphics-card, remote

My parents' PC's video card may be dead, or at least HDMI output produces nothing. I know that HDMI cable and monitor are OK. Is is possible to login into that PC somehow without opening it and replacing the video card? Something like ssh into it?

Comment: It depends on which Windows version and what settings were left active.  Definitely worth trying a connection through Remote Desktop (mstsc.exe)

Comment: How do you know it is the video card? A blank screen could mean all sorts of things. Probably a dead motherboard. If it has an add on video card, you can just remove it and use the onboard video which is typically available.

Comment: Windows can implement remote login through mstsc.exe, but only if the remote desktop connection of the computer is enabled, that is, we check Allow remote connection to this computer.
Control Panel\System and Security\System\Advanced system settings->Remote->Remote Desktop->Allow remote connection to this computer